# Is it possible to still interact with Fragments on the back-stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Referring to the Fragment documentation, specifically [Performing Fragment Transactions](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) it states:

> Whereas, if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment, then the fragment is **stopped** and will be resumed if the user navigates back.

I want to understand the implications of a Frgament being stopped because I am creating several Fragments which I would like to place on the BackStack yet must still interact with them from an external (i.e. non-GUI) thread, to set a flag within the Fragment for example. Also if the Fragment starts threads within it, are they too stopped or 'suspended' once the Fragment is placed onto the backstack?

Comment: i suppose best practices are pretty much the same for fragments and activities in this cituation and it's not a best idea to do something in already stopped fragment. What do you think about using your parent `Activity` to store your flags? And also one more question: how do you want to itteract with fragment that is already in backstack?

Comment: The fragment will receive data received across a network. This data is used to modify Views within the Fragment and also I may need to carry out further actions (within the Fragment) dependent on the data value. I do not want to have to wait for a particular Fragment to come back into view to have this (real-time) data to be acted upon.

Comment: But what does 'stopped' actually mean? Would a thread started in the Fragment be paused (stopped)?